# How to set a fallback to English for non-existing language in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, locale

I have a **i18n folder** with **7 csv files** which contain keys and translation into **7 different languages**.

Then I go into admin panel and in **General->Locale options**, I select a language which is contained in my **i18n folder**.
All works fine as expected (I see correct translation in frontend checkout page).

But when within admin panel, I select the **locale** which I don’t have in my **i18n folder**, then in frontend checkout page I only see translation keys (and not translation them selves).

> Is there a way to set a **default fallback language to English** for example, when the current selected language is not supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out one way of doing this: extend \Magento\Framework\Phrase\Renderer\Translate and the function “render”.

The “render” function normally returns a translation based on a translation key. If this is not the case and this function tries to return the translation key itself, this means the translation did not happen.

I fixed this problem by adding something like:

```
if ($translatedWord == $translationKey) { // translation did not happen
    return $englishTranslations[$translationKey];
}
```